# Trigger a button on the Enter work only in fulse password

Tags: html

I dont have much knowledge of HTML but I am trying to create a code that a person enters a password - if the password is correct the site will transfer to another site and if the password is incorrect an error message will pop up.
Very important - my goal is that they can use it without a computer mouse so it is important to me that the page works by pressing Enter.
I was able to create a code that actually works and when you press enter in the password field it does pop up a message that the code is incorrect (if indeed it is incorrect)

My problem - that when the code is correct and anter is pressed - that when the code is correct and I press enter I do not move to the next page - it only moves at the click of a button.
I mean that pressing Enter in the password field only works if the code is incorrect and does not perform the said operation when the code is correct.

Why? How do I fix the problem?

```
       <form id="login_form" autocomplete="off" class="form_class" method="post">
      <span><h2 style="text-align:center;">יש להקליד סיסמא באותיות קטנות ומספרים בלבד</h2></span>   
      <form name="login">
        <input type="text"
        id="txtSearch"
        onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13)
        document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"
        style="text-align:center;"
        name="password"
        placeholder="הקלד סיסמא"
        />
        <button type="button"
        id="btnSearch"
        onclick="check(this.form)"
        value="Login">אישור
        </button>
      </form>   
      <script language="javascript"> 
      function check(form) {
      if(form.password.value == "omg911") { window.open("**","_self")
}
      else { alert("קוד שגוי, נסה שנית") } } 
      </script>
```

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish but you can never ever check a password this way.

Answer (score 0):

because `<form></form>` as default action submit the form you should use `preventDefault()` to avoid submit action and do your custom action you can use it in your code like this...

```
function check(form) {
    if (form.password.value == "omg911") {
        // This line will prevent form submiting
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        })
        window.open("**", "_self")
    } else {
        alert("קוד שגוי, נסה שנית")
    }
}
```